# Getting started with SciPy and first example doesn't run

Tags: scipy

Environment is Ubuntu 12.x LTS 64 bit.  I ran the install as follows :

```
 sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

Everything installed great, and I tried out the 'getting started' example only to come upon this error as if my env. is't set correctly..

See orig @ http://www.scipy.org/getting-started.html

```
usernamep@ubuntudev:~$ ipython --pylab
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

Welcome to pylab, a matplotlib-based Python environment [backend: TkAgg].
For more information, type 'help(pylab)'.

In [1]: from scipy import special, optimize

In [2]: f = lambda x: -special.jv(3,x)

In [3]: sol = optimize.minimize(f, 1.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user/<ipython-input-3-ea43eb308d3c> in <module>()
----> 1 sol = optimize.minimize(f, 1.0)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'minimize'

In [4]:
```

Do I need to reform their example's import?  Checking their docs now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optimize.minimize` was introduced in Scipy v.0.11 (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html ).

[On Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=python-scipy), that would mean that you need Jessie or better.  [On Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=python-scipy), you appear to need raring or better.

Comment: linked it and everything, okay that explains it.  Thank you. 

To add this I should build from source? or can I somehow add the repository.

Comment: went ahead with sudo pip install numpy --upgrade, and repeated for scipy.  Thanks for linking the docs!

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly the `scipy` you installed using `apt-get` is simply too old to have `minimize`: (0.10, I'd guess).  The code works for me:

```
>>> from scipy import special, optimize
>>> def f(x): return -special.jv(3,x)
>>> sol = optimize.minimize(f, 1.0)
>>> sol
   status: 0
  success: True
     njev: 17
     nfev: 51
 hess_inv: array([[ 4.70024446]])
      fun: -0.43439442684052476
        x: array([ 4.20118891])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
      jac: array([ -3.72529030e-09])
```

I think you'll be better off using `pip` to install the stack.

Comment: I am going to try sudo pip install numpy --upgrade , and repeat for scipy.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

python-scipy package in the Ubuntu 12 is a bit old.  I think it is ver 0.9.0. The optimize.minimize function was added to scipy ver 0.11.0.